# Trying to use python with photos.capture_image() for Kairos enroll API

Tags: python, python-requests, http-post, photo, pythonista

I am currently messing around with the Kairos API and am trying to use Pythonista to take a new photo on my iPad and then upload that photo to the Kairos enroll API. I am able to get this to work fine with a URL image but for the life of me I am unable to get this to work by taking a photo with the photos module. From my understanding the photos module returns a PIL Image and I *think* I need to base64 encode that before uploading to the Kairos API??

Here is my code without using the photos module:

```
#import photos
import requests

#img = photos.capture_image()
url = "https://api.kairos.com/enroll"

values = """
  {
    "image": "https://images.pexels.com/photos/614810/pexels-photo-614810.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=face-facial-hair-fine-looking-614810.jpg&fm=jpg",
    "subject_id": "test",
    "gallery_name": "test"
  }
"""

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'app_id': '********',
    'app_key': '************************'
}

request = requests.post(url, data=values, headers=headers)
response = request.content

print(response)
```

Im hoping that someone can help me out by showing me what I need to do to be able to accomplish this task. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance,

Colin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this to work by converting the PIL Image with BytesIO and then encoding with base64:

```
with io.BytesIO() as output:
    img = photos.capture_image()
    img.save(output, 'JPEG')
    contents = output.getvalue()
    image = base64.b64encode(contents)
```

Hopefully this helps some in the future.